# How to build OCaml in M1 Mac with Zarith on it?

Tags: ocaml, isabelle

I am trying to do code generation with Isabelle/HOL in an M1 Mac computer. A recurring issue to achieve this relates to OCaml's library Zarith. I've asked in their mailing list and [their answer](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2021-April/msg00081.html) was that "the problem is
ultimately to build OCaml (with Zarith) on it". Unfortunately, I do not understand what the verb "build" means in that sentence. OCaml is in that computer as the report on the end of this question indicates. The computer has Zarith on it (version 1.12). However, as they say, there is an issue with Zarith in that system. The evidence that I have for this comes from two observations:

1. When I run `utop` and do `#require "zarith";;` the answer is:

```
Cannot load required shared library dllzarith.
Reason: /.../.opam/ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0/lib/stublibs/dllzarith.so: dlopen(/.../.opam/ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0/lib/stublibs/dllzarith.so, 0x000A): symbol not found in flat namespace '___gmpn_add_n'.
```

2. When opening an `.ml` file in Visual Studio Code with commands with types such as `Z.t` where `Z` represents `Zarith`, VSC complains with `Unbound module Z ocamllsp`.

The question is then, how do I make this computer find the Zarith files it needs to work properly?

```
% opam config report
# opam config report
# opam-version      2.0.8 
# self-upgrade      no
# system            arch=arm64 os=macos os-distribution=homebrew os-version=12.0.1
# solver            builtin-mccs+glpk
# install-criteria  -removed,-count[version-lag,request],-count[version-lag,changed],-changed
# upgrade-criteria  -removed,-count[version-lag,solution],-new
# jobs              7
# repositories      1 (http) (default repo at 8818dcc3)
# pinned            0
# current-switch    ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0
```

Comment: What's the console output when you run $ opam install zarith

Comment: @MarcusRohrmoser the only output I get after running `opam install zarith` is `[NOTE] Package zarith is already installed (current version is 1.12).`

Comment: uh, seems to be installed half-baked. Can you try in a newly created switch? E.g. $ opam switch create 4.12.1

Comment: @MarcusRohrmoser I manually created a new switch and installed `zarith` and `utop`. Utop now finds zarith. However, `ocamllsp` still does not find `zarith`. But you are on the right track. When I created a new switch and installed zarith via the Isabelle way (`isabelle ocaml_setup`), utop did not find zarith.

Comment: nice you're progressing, sad you're not through yet – can you ask the `ocamllsp` and `isabelle` folks, respectively?

Comment: @MarcusRohrmoser thanks! Yes, that seems like the logical next step to do.

Comment: `isabelle env | grep opam` gives your the path of opam used by Isabelle. With it you should be able to install zarith.

Comment: @MathiasFleury could you elaborate please? How does knowing the location of a specific opam switch help me to install zarith for that version?

Comment: I cannot help you on the opam side of things. Isabelle uses its own opam, so every manipulation you do on `opam` has to be mirrored on the isabelle opam to work.